# Integral depending measurable on a parameter

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measurable space and let $f\colon [0,1] \times \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be such that $x\mapsto f(t,x)$ is integrable for all $t\in [0,1]$. Then $$F\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R,\quad t\mapsto F(t) = \int_\Omega f(t,x) d\mu(x)$$ is well-defined.

---

*Question*: Are there mild conditions on $t\mapsto f(t,x)$ such that $F$ is measurable (perhaps even if $[0,1]$ is replaced by some measurable space)?

---

I have found the following well-known statements:

- If $t\mapsto f(t,x)$ is continuous for a.e. $x\in \Omega$ and if $|f(t,x)| \leq g(x)$ for all $(t,x)$ and some integrable $g$, then $F$ is known to be continuous.
- If $\Omega$ is $\sigma$-finite and $(x,t)\mapsto f(t,x)$ is integrable on the product-space, then $F$ is integrable and one can interchange the order of integration by Fubini's theorem.

Now I wonder, if one can drop continuity in $t$ without asking $f$ to be product-measurable.

Comment: Two comments: You only assume $x \mapsto f(t,x)$ to be **measurable** and claim that this ensures $F$ to be well-defined. This is not so. You need to assume that $x \mapsto f(t,x)$ is **integrable** for this to hold. Next, regarding your second well-known observation: It suffices to have $f$ measurable w.r.t. the product $\sigma$-algebra. Integrability is not needed. I doubt that there is a nice sufficient criterion which does **not** need the product measurability, but I might well be wrong.

Comment: Ah, yes. If $x\mapsto f(t,x)$ is only measurable, the positive or the negative part may have infinite integral. My fault, I will change the assumption.
But why is it that product-measurability of $f$ ensures that $F$ is well-defined?
Well, maybe someone knows a nice criterion, I will wait.